# For the function $f(x) = \lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{1}{1 + n\sin^2(\pi x)}$, what can be said about it's continuity at $x = 1$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

What can be said about the continuity of the following function at $x = 1$?

$$f(x) = \lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{1}{1 + n\sin^2(\pi x)}.$$

For the function shown what can be said about it's continuity at $x=1$, i.e. whether or not it is continuous?  A reason to support answer would be helpful.

Comment: You absolutely need to start learning [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) now. You've made several posts, including a couple of answers (kudos!), but it's not fair on us to continue formatting your posts for you. It's time for your to learn for yourself.

Comment: I am so overwhelmed with this brotherly rebuke I promise I will :)

Comment: Awesome! Good luck. I'm sure we can clean it up if your attempts don't quite work.

Comment: Write $(sin\pi{x})$$(sin\pi{x})$. Keep the first sine with the $n$ and consider a standard limit, the second term becomes zero.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: think about the expression
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + kn}.$$
For most values of $k$, this will be $0$. For one value of $k$, this will be $1$. If you can work this out, you can figure out an explicit expression for $f(x)$, and figure out directly if it is continuous at $x = 1$.